# difference between building a docker from ubuntu base image and python base image?

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, docker, dockerfile

Docker newbie here.

I was reading the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/) on how to setup Django webapp using Docker and I realized that the dockerfile uses

`FROM python:2.7`

Can I still use the same dockerfile contents but change it to

`FROM ubuntu:14.04`

and make it work with python 2.7 or 3.4 for Django 1.8.1?

Answer (score 2):

With ubuntu you can run a django app. you just have to install the dependencies for it (with instructions in your Dockerfile for example).

In your Dockerfile, add something like :

```
RUN apt-get install python
RUN apt-get install django
```

You may also have to replace some commands by their equivalent if they're not implemented in the new base image (replace `apt-get` by `pacman` if you use **archlinux** instead of **ubuntu** for example).

But if you use django, you also can install and use pip.

Answer (score 1):

The docker **FROM** instruction specifies the base image to start your image build.

If you go to the python:2.7 dockerfile you will see that it specifies the next:

```
FROM buildpack-deps:jessie
```

This means that this image will use the image *buildpack-deps:jessie* and on top of that it builds all python-related dependencies.

You could think about this as application layers. You set up base image (in the FROM statement) and then install whatever you need to launch your apps.

Example:

I need a image that has wget installed so I make a Dockerfile similar to this:

```
FROM debian:jessie
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install wget
...
```

And I could call this image: *wgetimage*. Then if I need a wget container to download somethind I could use this image:

```
FROM wgetimage
RUN wget ....
```

---

In this specific case the ubuntu base image won't have python related packages, so you will need to add them on the Dockerfile. If you only need to launch python apps, it's maybe better if you use python:2.7 (or python:3.4) as your base image.

Hope it helps.